# Raspberry Pi using a laptop?

Tags: hardware

So I tried using a laptop to install Raspberry Pi, without connecting the USB cable to a keyboard and mouse, but I am not seeing any Raspberry Pi display on my laptop screen?
Do I need a keyboard and mouse Raspberry pi to work or do can I just use my laptop which already comes with a keyboard and mouse?

Comment: This question is really confusing me. Do you want to use your laptop to control your Pi?

Comment: Raspberry Pis have a an OUTPUT HDMI, your laptop has an OUTPUT HDMI. You TV has an INPUT HDMI, your monitor has an INPUT HDMI. You can ONLY connect an output to an input (if you expect anything to work). So try again.

Comment: Do I need a keyboard and mouse Raspberry pi to work or do can I just use my laptop which already comes with a keyboard and mouse?

Comment: You need a Micro (regular if Pi1) SD card for the Raspberry Pi to boot. Have you even installed an OS?

Comment: Yes I did. That;s not the problem.

Comment: Do I need a keyboard and mouse if I already have a laptop?

Comment: No. You do not *need* it.

Comment: You can set up SSH and access it remotely.

Comment: And if you want a graphical desktop, configure the RPi over SSH to use VNC

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the Pi up to work in headless mode.

First thing is to enable command line access by following the instructions [part way down here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md) (section 3).

Once that is up and running, you can enable VNC to allow graphical mode by following the instructions [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md)

All the programs mentioned are free to use with the Pi.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not seeing any Raspberry Pi display on my laptop screen

## Your laptop is not a video screen.

You cannot display the Pi output on your laptop by connecting them with an HDMI cable for the same reason **you cannot display anything on your laptop via the HDMI port**.

If you really believe this is an Rpi issue, try plugging a set-top box or smart TV device (or anything intended to be plugged into an HDMI display) into it.  It will not work.

I do not know whether it is possible *to cause permanent damage* by using the connectors wrongly this way, but it might be, so be sure to consider this before applying my last suggestion (or plugging your pi into your laptop again).